# In which .php file does the "subtract stock" happens after a successful order?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am using **Opencart v.2.1.0.2** and I am trying to find the **.php** file where the "subtract stock" happens after a successful order.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look for it in **\catalog\model\checkout\order.php**

The update of product quantity

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET quantity = (quantity - " . (int)$order_product['quantity'] . ") WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$order_product['product_id'] . "' AND subtract = '1'");
```

The update of product options quantity

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET quantity = (quantity - " . (int)$order_product['quantity'] . ") WHERE product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$option['product_option_value_id'] . "' AND subtract = '1'");
```

Although there are restock querys, if the order is cancelled.

Comment: I want to note `subtract = '1'`. inside product you can edit whether subtract or not